# C# Implementing inteface

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I would like to implement interface if it is possible, but can't do it myself.

I have two methods:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Send([FromBody] EmailDto email)
    {
        //send email
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> SendMany([FromBody] EmailManyDto email)
    {
        //send email
    }
```

and I have two classes:

```
public class EmailDto 
{
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class EmailManyDto
{
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to merge these two endpoints into one endpoint.
I think I should implement the most general interface as possible - IEnumerable to receive recipients.

Generaly I need to refactor this code someway.

Comment: If your goal is to just email one person but you want to reuse the same code, you could just add a single person to your list. Problem solved. I don't think you really needed us to tell you that.

Comment: Take a look at the basics - `System.Net.MailMessage.MailMessage` has a `To` property that is a `System.Net.Mail.MailAddressCollection`. You can simply use a list in the email dto

Comment: _"General[l]y I need to refactor this code someway"_ this is very unspecific and too broad a question. I think you need to be more specific about what _exactly_ you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @justme I think this is a good question, but is not well-suited for stack overflow since it's basically asking for code review / design suggestions. It would do better here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You could create a DTO that accepts both one and multiple email addresses:

```
public class EmailManyDto
{
    public string Recipient 
    {
        get
        {
            return Recipients.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            Recipients.Insert(0, value);
        }
    }
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

This way your old clients will continue to work, and you can refactor your code into one method.

By storing the single recipient at the start of the list, you can unify your code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendMany([FromBody] EmailManyDto email)
{
    foreach (var recipient in email.Recipients)
    {
        // send your mail
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea but wouldn't it be better to remove the `get` accessor altogether?

Comment: And maybe even change the `set` to something like `set { Recipients = new List<string>() { value }; }`.